# How to replace javascript prototype with custom function

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
// I am trying to make a clone of String's replace function
// and then re-define the replace function (with a mind to
// call the original from the new one with some mods)
String.prototype.replaceOriginal = String.prototype.replace
String.prototype.replace = {}
```

This next line is now broken - how do I fix?

```
"lorem ipsum".replaceOriginal(/(orem |um)/g,'')
```

Comment: It works fine for me (in Firefox). It might help if you would explain what "broken" means.

Comment: Agreed, it works fine in Chrome too: http://jsfiddle.net/4hPhG/

Comment: The only thing I can see that is wrong in your code is the missing `;` on the first statement.

Comment: Your updated code is not a function.

Comment: my updated code more accurately reflects what I want to do. It is not a function, but what I am trying to do is to clone the replace function, rather than set a pointer to it, so that unsetting it does not break the cloned copy.

Comment: @BillyMoon Your updated example does not make any sense. Can you elaborate it? What about showing the real code, if it's not too big?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The only possible issue is that your code is executed twice, which causes problems: The real original `.replace` will disappear.

To avoid such problems, I strongly recommend to replace built-in methods using the following general method:

```
(function(replace) {                         // Cache the original method
    String.prototype.replace = function() {  // Redefine the method
        // Extra function logic here
        var one_plus_one = 3;
        // Now, call the original method
        return replace.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(String.prototype.replace);
```

- This allows multiple method modifications **without** breaking existing functionality
- The context is preserved by [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply): Usually, the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) object is vital for (prototype) methods.

Comment: There can be other issues. For example (just hypothetically) that `replace` is recursive and in certain cases calls "itself" using `this.replace(...)` with different parameters (except that it wouldn't call itself but another incompatible method). In general replacing a predefined method with an incompatible one is not going to work unless you also know exactly which predefined method calls which. This is not different from replacing a function with an incompatible one in a normal library without knowing the dependence graph.

Comment: This was exactly right - I was executing twice, so the original was getting overwritten. Schoolboy error. Thanks for the thorough answer with some other useful pointers.