# Override .load function of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, overriding

I have site which uses $(selector).load(path) function in more than 300 pages. Now my client's requirement has changed and I need to access cross domain to call these pages.

For the purpose I have to replace all the .load( function to some cross-domain function with the help of YQL.

Is it possible to override my .load function and call prevent default and do my own code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace javascript prototype with custom function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057931/how-to-replace-javascript-prototype-with-custom-function) - Exact the same answer, just replace `String.prototype.replace` with `jQuery.prototype.load` or `$.fn.load`.

Comment: @RobW: Whilst I sort of agree, `load` might be considered a special case because of the problems ThiefMaster outlines... prehaps this isn't a total duplicate.

Comment: @RobW. You do know that you can close **all** the questions in this site as duplicated if you go with that line of thinking...

Comment: I don't think it's really a dupe. The OP's intention is to modify one specific part of `.load()` which is not easily done by simply replacing the whole function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no clean way to do this, especially since `$.fn.load` does different things depending on the arguments and replacing it would affect all those subfunctions.

However, jQuery [supports AJAX hooks](http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/) which you might be able to achieve what you want.

In case all you need is support for IE's XDomainRequest, have a look at this plugin: https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/ajax/xdr.js

---

Anyway, if you really want to replace the ajax load function of jQuery, this code should do it:

```
var _load = $.fn.load;
$.fn.load = function(url, params, callback) {
    if(typeof url !== "string") {
        return _load.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    // do your ajax stuff here
}
```

This is exactly the same check jQuery uses to decide whether someone wants to bind the `onload` event or perform an AJAX load.

Comment: Your guidance worked like charm! Thanks. A quick tip is required. My default .load( funciton is like "$(selector).load(pathA).html(pathT);" how to handel this .html( in the code you provided above.

Comment: or somehow, the .html( code being called can be ignored. As currently JS is ending up in error saying 'Object doesn't support property or method html'

Comment: You need to `return this;` to permit method chaining.

Answer (score 5):

The most reasonnable way seems to me to not overload the jquery function but simply do a search and replace in your favorite editor to replace `$(xxx).load(` by `yourpackage.load(xxx,`.

This can be done in minutes even on 300 js files. Future changes will be easier and the code will be more readable as **the reader never expects a jquery function to do something that isn't on the doc**.

Comment: Actually, it would be better to replace `.load(` with something like `.customLoad(` and store the new in `$.fn.customLoad`.

Comment: Depends. I like to have my functions clearly distinguishable from the jquery ones. But that's just a detail, a matter of taste and the choice should be coherent with the rest of the project.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible:

```
$.fn.load = yourFunc;
```

**Is it recommended? I think not.**

Comment: The big problem I see is that the maintainer will ask us why `$(xxx).load(` doesn't do what it's supposed to do according to jquery's doc. When you start doing this, your maintainers need to read the whole code in order to understand just a part...

Comment: @dystroy. You're right. I don't like people modifying libraries, this why I wrote it's not recommended.

Comment: @dystroy You all are right to not to over-ride default functionalities, but in my case. The site is doing fine at it own, like www.xyz.com it will do all the .load( operations. In addition, i have to access the same site from another domain and Scirpt on this domain will override .load funciton of page loaded from the called domain. .... fuuuh!! I am sure you won't get what am i doing :)

Comment: I got what you said. But still this could be managed in a cleaner way using your own function (which could be overloaded or parameterized in a simple point).