# Overloading the .load() function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have inherited some code which makes abundant use of the `jQuery.load()` function, however there are some occasions where what is being loaded is json and as a result, the raw json gets displayed to the user.

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to fix this without having to go through all the code and change all the instances of `.load()`.

Is it possible to overload the `load()` function in order to detect whether what is being loaded is json, and if it is then call a custom function that will parse the json and return HTML to be loaded into the element?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11153883/2518525) might be of use

Comment: Sounds like an ugly band-aid.